# jQuery smooth page transition with preloader

Tags: jquery, transition, fadein, smoothing

I try to use this code (below) to fade in a div content when I press a link in my website, than fade out when I press another link and the new content come fade in. You can see this example here:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

Well, I need to put an animate gif preloader on top of every page before it will be loaded. Could someone help me with the jquery code? 
Thanks..

Code to swap content and fadein/out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").css("display", "none");
    $("#content").fadeIn(1000);
    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#content").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
    });
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code that page will lead to very non-slick "flickering" as the new page loads, then is hidden at $(document).ready() before fading back in.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to add a loading overlay.

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("#content").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);    
    $("body").append("<div class='LoadingOverlay' />");
}
```

And then use CSS to control how it is rendered.

```
.LoadingOverlay
{
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    width:124px;
    height:124px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-62px;
    margin-right:-62px;
    background-image:url(/images/loading51.gif);
}
```

Normally I do this once the new ajax call is complete

```
 $(".LoadingOverlay").remove();
```

But it looks like you'll be loading a new page once the preload is complete, so you won't need this.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but where I have to insert this:

Comment: Thank you, but I need a complete code to include in mine, because I'm newbie in Jquesry..thanks

Comment: Updated to show where to to insert the append() call.  Put the CSS in your CSS file.  You don't need the remove() call.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(".overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(".overlay").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

.overlay div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="spinner-border text-secondary">
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div> Helloo World</div>
</body>
```